# Executable LibGDX Jar File doesn't load assets

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, assets

My LibGDX project runs in Eclipse but when I export it to an executable JAR file I get "Couldn't load file: play_button_inactive.png" and "File not found: play_button_inactive.png (Internal)".

I refreshed and cleaned the project. I deleted my assets link in the Desktop Project and re-loaded it in the Build Path but the same errors persisted.

I looked inside the jar file and Eclipse packaged in the assets separately into the Jar file so I put them all into a new "assets" folder manually but I got the same errors when I ran it. I used the command

```
java -jar fileName.jar
```

Here is my Build Path.

[image: Build-Path 1]

[image: Build-Path 2]

Thanks for any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**: After reading around I found a solution which is to put all the assets into the same directory as the jar file. Is there any way to package them into the jar file?

Comment: Run gradlew desktop:dist from the command line.

Comment: When I run this in the directory of the jar file it says "'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: If you have Gradle installed, you can use gradle instead of gradlew. Not sure why your project is missing the Gradle wrapper. The LibGDX setup app automatically puts it in your project. You could create a new project with the LibGDX setup app and then copy over the gradle directory and gradlew.bat.

Comment: If its not recognizing gradle, but you have it installed you have to add gradle path to your environment variable PATH.

Comment: I created executable jar, its working fine.

Comment: Yes I now have the gradle wrapper and I ran the command. The build was successful.

Comment: You can package them into the jar file if you make sure the appropriate FileHandles are classpath handles: `FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.classpath("myfile.txt");`

Comment: How would I package them into the jar file? Would I add these handles to the classpath to package them into the jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by not using Eclipse's jar file building tools and used `gradlew desktop:dist` instead.

This works perfectly and packages all resources and files into the generated jar file.